# Steps for annual maintenance on a fuel oil furnace?

Tags: repair, furnace, maintenance

We have fuel oil and this year I'd like to try and maintenance the furnace myself:

[image]

[image]

[image]

By "*maintenance*" I mean "clean it up so that it runs well throughout the winter." Just a basic tuneup and cleaning. Maybe some small parts replacements if they're not in great shape, etc. Not sure where to start or what the steps involved would be. Any ideas where I could dig in?

Comment: You might want to find out what your home insurance company thinks of the idea.  They'd also be interested in your leaking oil tank...

Comment: Thanks @User58220 - there's nothing in my homeowner's policy that prevents me from doing light maintenance on my own furnace, no more than there would be anything preventing me from re-roofing my garage or putting a new fence in around my pool. Also, what do you see that indicates my oil tank is leaking? That stain has been there since we bought the home and hasn't grown at all; no oil has pooled anywhere, etc.

Comment: In Ontario, oil-fired heating systems must be inspected by licensed technicians before any oil can be delivered. And my insurance company required the replacement of an indoor, fault-free oil tank, based simply on age, or else no renewal......

Comment: Ahh, I'm in NY. Homeowners can do anything to everything. I guess its both good and bad, or in my case, bood.